# Inconsistent conversion of QVariant to double

Tags: c++, qt, qvariant

I'm having trouble understanding the behaviour of `QVariant::canConvert` and `QVariant::toDouble`. I'd expect that both of these would return false if the underlying variant data is, say, a `QString`, but I'm getting different results as shown:

```
#include <QString>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QString not_a_number("foo");
    QVariant variant(not_a_number);

    auto can_convert_1 = variant.canConvert<double>();
    auto can_convert_2 = false;
    variant.toDouble(&can_convert_2);

    qDebug() << can_convert_1 << can_convert_2; //prints: true false
}
```

The method `canConvert` returns true whereas the `toDouble` return false.
Can someone explain this behaviour please?

I'm using Qt 5.15.7 on Windows with Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double QVariant::toDouble(bool *ok = nullptr) const
```

and

```
template <typename T> bool QVariant::canConvert() const
```

have two very different meanings. `bool* ok` will return true if the conversion **has actually succeded**, while `canConvert()` tell if the source type ***could*** be converted to the destination type.

`QString` can be converted to `double`? ***Maybe***.

`QString` is one of the type allowed to be converted to double? Yes, so `canConvert()` will always return `true`, but `toDouble()` of course will fail.

Indeed if you try

```
auto convert = [](auto&& string){
   QString not_a_number(string);
   QVariant variant(not_a_number);

   auto can_convert_1 = variant.canConvert<double>();
   auto can_convert_2 = false;
   variant.toDouble(&can_convert_2);

   qDebug() << can_convert_1 << can_convert_2;
};

convert("foo");
convert("5");
```

will print

```
true false
true true
```

Both are QString, so canConvert succed, toDouble only succed for "5" can actually be converted to double.